# Highcharts - Formatter issues in IE

Tags: highcharts

I am having trouble getting a formatter function in my yaxis to work in IE 7 and 8. It is used to change the colors if the values are greater than zero. Works great in other browsers and IE 9.

I have used a formatter to change the color of the tooltip and that works in IE but the following in the Y-axis does not. Any ideas?

```
yAxis: {
labels: {
        formatter: function() {
    if(this.value > 0 ){
        return  '<span style="fill: #4572a7;font-weight:800;">' + '$' + this.value + '</span>';
    }
    else {
        return  '<span style="fill: red;font-weight:800;">' + '-$' + Math.abs(this.value) + '</span>'
    }
    }
    },
    alternateGridColor: '#F5F5F5',
    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickWidth: 1
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because highcharts uses VML in IE7/8 as svg is not supported and the fill CSS property is an svg style and would not be supported. Try using color instead of fill. It should play nicely with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to set useHTML as true, and replace fill with color css declaration:

```
yAxis: {
        labels: {
            useHTML:true,
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.value > 0) {
                    return '<span style="color: #4572a7;font-weight:800;">' + '$' + this.value + '</span>';
                } else {
                    return '<span style="color: red;font-weight:800;">' + '-$' + Math.abs(this.value) + '</span>'
                }
            }
        },
        alternateGridColor: '#F5F5F5',
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1
    },
```